# Ceiling fan replacement with old wiring issue

Tags: electrical

My house was built in 1890 and has a mix of newer and old wiring. We have a bedroom that had an older ceiling fan that we decided to replace with a new one that is closer to the ceiling itself (low profile). The new one is actually a smaller fixture than the old one.

Now the **Problem**: When taking the old fan down the wires were not labeled on the ceiling fan or the wires in the box. The wiring in the metal box above the ceiling is older and we cannot tell what is what.

There are two sets of similar looking wires that have been twisted together and one singular wire that hangs down further but has a slight copper color to the very end of it. All wires appear to have a cloth sleeve over them but hard to tell exact color. There is a single light switch in the room. See picture of wiring below (sorry about the lack of lighting):

[image: actual picture of wiring coming from the metal box in the ceiling]

We have a regular circuit breaker (it is not the older fuses) and the one to this room is currently off while we figure this out. Any advice on how to figure this out would be appreciated.

Comment: Was this just a fan, or a fan/light combo?

Comment: Fan/light combo

Comment: How do you want to control the fan and light?

Comment: We just have one light switch for power to it. Pull chains on the unit will suffice.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter or voltmeter?

Comment: I could get one.

Comment: If you can, that would be great, please